# Can't pass $stateParams into view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a value using `ui-sref` and stateParams, but it isn't working. Here is my code:

StateProvider part:

```
// Test page
.state("test", {
    url: "/test/:cid",
    templateUrl: "views/test.html",
    data: {pageTitle: 'Test Page'},
    controller: "GeneralPageControllerWithId"
})
```

Controller part:

```
angular.module('AppName').controller('GeneralPageControllerWithId', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'settings', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $scope, settings, stateParams) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {   
        // initialize core components
        App.initAjax();

        var cid = stateParams.cid;

        $scope.cid = cid;

        // set default layout mode
        $rootScope.settings.layout.pageContentWhite = true;
        $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = false;
        $rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = false;
    });
}]);
```

HTML part:

```
<a ui-sref="test({ cid : 1 })">Test</a>
```

Output HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="GeneralPageControllerWithId">
Test content {{ cid }}
</div>
```

The output is printing `{{ cid }}` as shown, and not displaying 1 as I thought. I want to pass ID variables through the URL but for some reason it's just not working.  How do I pass a `stateParam` using `ui-sref` in Angular?

Comment: there is a comma missing on the controller, before the function declaration with the inject params

Comment: I'm not seeing the spot where its missing.

Comment: '$stateParams' function

Comment: Got it. That didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma missing on the first line of your controller file.

```
angular.module('AppName').controller('GeneralPageControllerWithId',['$rootScope','$scope','settings','$stateParams' function($rootScope,$scope,settings,stateParams) {...}
```

should read:

```
angular.module('AppName').controller('GeneralPageControllerWithId',['$rootScope','$scope','settings','$stateParams', function($rootScope,$scope,settings,stateParams) {...}
```

Notice the added comma between "'$stateParams'" and "function." You may also want to add the dollar sign ($) prefix before "stateParams" in your functions arguments for consistency.

Comment: Yeah I've been playing with that back and forth. I did what you said and it's still printing as {{ cid }}.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the controller should read as

```
angular.module('AppName')
.controller('GeneralPageControllerWithId', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'settings', '$stateParams', 
function($rootScope, $scope, settings, $stateParams) {
...your stuff goes here
}]);
```

There is comma(,) missing before function and a dollar($) missing before the second stateParams.

also

```
$scope.cid = $stateParams.cid;
```